# Получение даты через String.format()

Tags: java, android

Есть код  для Android,цель выводить имя месяца:

```
    day_of_month = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.day_of_month);
    day_of_week = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.day_of_week);
    String month_s = String.format("%1$tB",new Date());
    String day_s = String.format("%1$tA",new Date());
    month.setText(month_s);
    day_of_week.setText(day_s);
```

Все хорошо,кроме падежа месяца:он выводиться как Марта,Февраля,Сентября и т.д,то есть в родительном падеже.Как вывести в именительном:Март,Февраль,Сентябрь?

Благодаря ответу код приобрёл такой вид:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy;LLLL;dd;EEEE");
    String date_string = String.format("%s",format.format(new Date()));
    String[] date_array = date_string.split(";");
    year.setText(date_array[0]);
    month.setText(date_array[1]);
    day_of_month.setText(","+date_array[2]);
    day_of_week.setText(date_array[3]);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

По-моему, через `String.format` - никак. С API 9 можно воспользоваться `SimpleDateFormat` с параметром `"L"` (stand-alone month):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat( "LLLL" );
System.out.printf( "sdf: %s%n", format.format( new Date() ) ); // sdf: Март
```

Аналогичный параметр для дня недели - `"c"`, хотя для русского языка это не важно.

Comment: ,спасибо,помогло.А где вы нашли эту форму "LLLL"?Вот здесь я её не увидел https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: @NoAppYet Для андроида лучше смотреть [документацию](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) на их сайте, стандартные классы иногда немного различаются. Еще по вашей ссылке - док от SE 7, в SE 8 SimpleDateFormat поддерживает "LLLL".